# How to move files one folder to another only if it's empty?

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to move files from `D:\work\` to  `"D:\new work"` only if `"D:\new work"` folder is empty. will it be possible using batch script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
dir /a-d "D:\new work\*" && (echo Contains files) || (move /Y "D:\work\* "D:\new work")
```

if there might be sub-folders to check for being empty, then just add `/s`

```
dir /a-d /s "D:\new work\*" && (echo Contains files) || (move /Y "D:\work\*" "D:\new work")
```